# Sting manipulation won't print full output to input

Tags: java, string

I have code for string manipulation but the output only generates the first name and not the rest of the input. I don't get any errors so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Can someone show point out what I'm doing wrong if so and help me fix it so the output shows everything?

The expected input and output is for first name, last name, full name, upper case full name, lower case full name, number of vowels, number of consonants, and a few sentences plus the date.

Here is the code -

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringManipulation {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
      
       System.out.println("Enter first name: Bk ");
       String fName = input.next();
      
       System.out.println("Enter last name: Codeman");
       String lName = input.next();
      
       String UserFullName = fName.concat(" ").concat(lName);
       System.out.println("\nHello " + UserFullName);
       System.out.println("Length of name: " + UserFullName.length());
      
       UserFullName = UserFullName.toUpperCase();
       System.out.println("\nIn Upper Case: " + UserFullName);
      
       UserFullName = UserFullName.toLowerCase();
       System.out.println("In Lower Case: " + UserFullName);
      
       //Counter variable to store the count of vowels and consonant
int vCount = 0, cCount = 0;   
  
for(int i = 0; i < UserFullName.length(); i++) {
//Checks whether a character is a vowel
if(UserFullName.charAt(i) == 'a' || UserFullName.charAt(i) == 'e' || UserFullName.charAt(i) == 'i' || UserFullName.charAt(i) == 'o' || UserFullName.charAt(i) == 'u') {
//Increments the vowel counter
vCount++;
}
//Checks whether a character is a consonant
else if(UserFullName.charAt(i) >= 'a' && UserFullName.charAt(i)<='z') {
//Increments the consonant counter
cCount++;
}
}
  
System.out.println("\nNumber of vowels: " + vCount);
System.out.println("Number of consonants: " + cCount);
  
String text = "I am a very good student who works hard";
System.out.println("\nText: " + text);
System.out.println("At Position 10 of Text: " + text.charAt(10));
System.out.println("good starts at position: " + text.indexOf("good"));
System.out.println("good ends at position: " + (text.indexOf("good") + "good".length()-1));
  
System.out.println("\nEnter the word Excellent");
String word = input.next();
while(!word.equals("Excellent")) {
   System.out.println("Incorrect, enter again");
   word = input.next();
}
  
System.out.println("Good job");
  
Date date = new Date();
   SimpleDateFormat formatter;
   String strDate;
  
   System.out.println("\nCurrent Date and Time");
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy");
   strDate = formatter.format(date);
   System.out.println(strDate);
  
   formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a");
   strDate = formatter.format(date);
   System.out.println(strDate);
input.close();
   }
}
```

Comment: Please provide a more [mre].

Comment: You should provide your input, your current output and your expected output alongside your question.

Comment: The expected input and output is for first name, last name, full name, upper case full name, lower case full name, number of vowels, number of consonants, and a few sentences plus the date.

Comment: This code works perfectly. Please more clearly identify the exceptional condition you are trying to correct.

Comment: Randy idk why but my code is only printing my first name and nothing else, I'm trying to make it print everything in the input to the output

Answer (score 0):

I happen to run your program and i have no errors and also the desired output was obtained can you check again or please inform if this ain't the output you seek

```
Enter first name: Bk 
Stannars
Enter last name: Codeman
Jose

Hello Stannars Jose
Length of name: 13

In Upper Case: STANNARS JOSE
In Lower Case: stannars jose

Number of vowels: 4
Number of consonants: 8

Text: I am a very good student who works hard
At Position 10 of Text: y
good starts at position: 12
good ends at position: 15

Enter the word Excellent
Excellent
Good job

Current Date and Time
May 31, 2021
11:19 AM
```

Comment: Idk what's going on with mine, all the output prints is my first name...

Comment: i am using spring tool suite 4.5.1 with jdk 1.8 - have you tried clean project if so how about creating a new application ..

Comment: Do you mean starting a new project, and creating new classes?

Comment: can you tell me how to install spring tool suite? I have been trying to but the self-extracting.jar file keeps getting blocked, and I have been reading everywhere how to unblock but can't find

Comment: just double clicking and opening self extracting jar works if not you can also extract the jar file using winrar or something and open the sts found inside, it might not be in the root of extraction but inside a folder => which is only folder required.... comment if still stuck